# Why do my validation accuracy vary so much?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have almost 600K rows of data with 26 features. Training a neural network for classification and accuracy on validation set varies from 99 to 25. In some epochs it reaches 99 while in the next epoch itself sometimes it is dropping to 25. What could be the possible reason of this.

Comment: Your question is too broad for SO. We cannot help you without knowing anything about the data or the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Even though your answer is very broad, this might help you out. I found a good answer on StackExchange.*

Check out [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/255105/why-is-the-validation-accuracy-fluctuating) answer, I think that this could be happening because some parts of the validation data points are just classified randomly. Having 26 different features could be a big disadvantage -> the classifier might not be able to find patterns because some features are just noisy, not precise enough or even counteract your purpose, which ends in random classifications.

Another possible problem is your learning rate. If it is too low, you could miss good spots on the loss landscape. And therefore hit good or bad spots depending on your luck.

**My suggestion** is to do some data science to find the features that have the biggest impact on the outcome. Have a look at [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/feature-selection-techniques-in-machine-learning-with-python-f24e7da3f36e) medium article to find some good techniques. And if that doesn't bring you anywhere, try some regularization techniques and choose a proper learning rate.

And if nothing works, give us a better insight on your dataset and details on your training.

Comment: Thanks , I figured out what the problem was. Due to one hot encoding dimensions were increasing to a huge number and data was too less. Thus it was approximating very good. Now I have fixed it but now I can only achieve 60% accuracy. Do you have any suggestions on how many layers to use in my neural network?

Comment: are you seeing any signs of overfitting? -> Use fewer layers and a simpler structure. If the opposite is true, try out more layers.